# How to read a text has many languages using chrome.tts.speak API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, text-to-speech, ssml

I want to use tts [chrome extensions API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tts/#ssml-markup) to read a text with multiple languages.

I tried this

```js
const english = (await chrome.tts.getVoices()).find(x => x.lang === "en-US").voiceName

const danish = (await chrome.tts.getVoices()).find(x => x.lang === "da-DK").voiceName

await chrome.tts.speak(`
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<speak version="1.0">
  <voice name="${danish}">
        Jeg er glad for at se dig
  </voice>
  <voice name="${english}">
        I'm good to see you
  </voice>
</speak>
`);
```

But it reads both texts as English texts.

Comment: Does it read all text including xml, version, speak, voice, name, etc or only `Jeg er glad for at se dig` and `I'm good to see you`?

Comment: It read both considering them as English text

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with [`document fragmentation`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tts/#ssml-markup). I also tried this using the back-tick same way as you're doing and it uttered all the words even the tags, attributes, question marks of xml. Then I changed to this:

```
chrome.tts.speak(
'<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
'<speak>' +
  `<voice name=${danish}>` +
      'Jeg er glad for at se dig' +
  '</voice>' +
  `<voice name=${english}>` +
      "I am good to see you" +
  '</voice>' +
'</speak>'
);
```

and it worked.

Comment: Doesn't work to me unfortunately. It doesn't read anything like this

Comment: I'm running this on an M1 macbook pro. Where are you running this? How is this text `Jeg er glad for at se dig` read on your machine?

Comment: I'm on WIn11 + Chrome 105. It doesn't read the text `Jeg er glad for at se dig` at all.
I'm thinking to do it using `chrome.tts.speak` twice for each text

Comment: You could also try to specify `<lang xml:lang="da">Jeg er glad for at se dig</lang>` and see if that works.